# Redis queues in Laravel with Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, virtual-machine

I'm trying to use Redis for my queues.

Currently I'm on Homestead and I run `php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3` in my virtual machine.

To test queues I write something in the log. When I use the **sync** driver, the logger can write, but it cannot when I use the **redis** one.

I also checked out the running processes and the `redis-server` is running, what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `redis-cli monitor` and see if it shows anything being added when you push to the queue.

If nothing shows up, it means the queue isn't actually talking to redis.